# php curl get json and decode then display, fails displays nothing

Tags: php, json, curl

hello my teacher has given me this weeks work and i need to get my json data from a url and display it as php using json_decode, the php json file which i access with the url displays the songs as an json array and works fine, and i copied my teachers curl example to access the url, but it fails to display anything what have i done wrong ?

Edit: i do need to enter a password and username to access the url so i changed the code as told, but still nothing displays, i changed the password and username for security but the format and length are the same

```
<?php
$username = "2foobar90";
$password = "123456";
// Initialise the cURL connection
$connection = curl_init();

curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);  
// Specify the URL to connect to - DOUBLE CLICK link to test 
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, "https://edward2.solent.ac.uk/~martine/year3/hits.php?artist=David+Bowie");


// This option ensures that the HTTP response is *returned* from curl_exec(),
// (see below) rather than being output to screen.  
curl_setopt($connection,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

// Do not include the HTTP header in the response.
curl_setopt($connection,CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// Actually connect to the remote URL. The response is 
// returned from curl_exec() and placed in $response.
$response = curl_exec($connection);

// Close the connection.
curl_close($connection);

$data = json_decode($response, true);

for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++)
{
    echo "Song id " . $data[$i]["songid"] . " " .
         "Title " . $data[$i]["title"] . " " .
         "Artist " . $data[$i]["artist"] . " " .
         "Chart position " . $data[$i]["chart"] . "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Just as a note both files are on the same server, in the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link requires basic authentication. Your browser remembers your username/password when you click the link. You can see request headers with chrome inspector.

1. Click link
2. Open your browser inspector
3. Click Network section
4. Find document
5. You can see Authorization data under the Request Headers

[image]

If you want to use authorization with curl add this:

```
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
```